# How to make array of base class with random names?

Tags: c++

Base class: Staff
derived class1: admin
derived class2: academic

My question is that how to create a list of 50 staff objects with random names, and for each staff it should be randomly admin staff or academic staff.

```
class staff{
private: int name, int ID;
public: 
    staff(int name, int ID){
         this->name = name;
         this->ID = ID; 
    }
};

class academic:public staff{
public:
    academic(int name, int ID):staff(name,ID){}
};

class admin:public staff{
public:
    admin(int name, int ID):staff(name,ID){}
};
```

if i want to make `staff *[10]`; 
it should contain academic and admin randomly selected staff and random names.

Thank you

Comment: You should probably start out with giving us working and valid code examples of what you've already tried.

Comment: i m  confused here. i cant think of a way to do this. i can use rand() to give names to the staff list, but how it can be randomly academic or admin staff??

Comment: You make the base class staff polymorphic (e.g. declare a `virtual ~staff() {}` destructor, and have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<staff>> x;`. Then you fill that vector with instances of either `academic` or `admin` instances according the results of your `rand()` call.

Comment: so if i make virtual ~staff(){}, it will either be academic or admin both?

Comment: You're sure that the name is an integer ?

Comment: @Christophe name is string but can i generate random string? i dont think so .

Comment: @HasnainAli _"is string but can i generate random string?"_ Well, there are several ways to do this: 1. Randomly chosen characters and length 2. Choose (name) strings from a `std::map<int,std::string>` pool ...

Answer (score 2):

You have lots of other issues with your code that you should address in order for it to be correct (currently, it doesn't even compile).  However, you could do the following.

```
std::random_device random_device;
std::mt19937 engine{random_device()};
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> die_distribution;

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<staff>> people;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    if (die_distribution (engine) % 2)
    {
        people.emplace_back (new admin{die_distribution(engine), die_distribution(engine)});
    }
    else
    {
        people.emplace_back (new academic{die_distribution(engine), die_distribution(engine)});
    }
}
```

You'll need to include the `vector`, `memory`, and `random` headers to make this work.

---

If for some reason you cannot use the `random` header, you can use the older "random" number facilities.  Include `cstdlib` and `ctime`.

```
std::srand (std::time(0));
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<staff>> people;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    if (std::rand() % 2)
    {
        people.emplace_back (new admin{ std::rand(), std::rand() });
    }
    else
    {
        people.emplace_back (new academic{ std::rand(), std::rand() });
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry micheal, is there any better solution without using <random>

Comment: _@Michael Price_ That code perfectly reflects what I had in mind, THX.

Comment: @HasnainAli You can get something similar with just using `::rand()` as well, it's just that the reliability for the random distribution of your results may be more poor.